# AppWidget in Accounts & Sync not getting updated

Tags: android

I've successfully gotten an AppWidget working on the home screen, which properly updates in response to pushes from a running background service.  I'm thinking this proves my overall logic and creation of AppWidgets.  I also have my sync adapter working correctly and have a sync settings profile built which properly functions with application preferences.

I would like to embed the running AppWidget within my specific account settings page in the "Accounts & Sync" tab from the OS.  Here's the XML for the account preference screen:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="general_description"
    android:summary="@string/preferences_general_description"
    >
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="General Settings" />

<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="account_information"
    android:title="@string/preferences_account_information_title">
    <intent android:targetPackage="@string/package_name"
        android:targetClass="com.dashwire.android.app.AccountInformationSettingsActivity"/>
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="sync_settings"
    android:title="@string/preferences_syncsettings_title"
    android:summary="@string/preferences_syncsettings_summary">
    <intent android:targetPackage="@string/package_name" 
        android:targetClass="com.dashwire.android.app.SyncSettingsActivity"/>
</PreferenceScreen>

<PreferenceScreen 
    android:key="sync_notifications"
    android:title="@string/preferences_syncsettings_notifications">
    <intent android:targetPackage="@string/package_name"
        android:targetClass="com.dashwire.android.app.ApplicationsActivity"/>
</PreferenceScreen>

<Preference
    android:key="squarepants"
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/appwidget_layout"/>
```

The AppWidget shows up, it's just not being updated like the working "Home Screen" is...  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only embed app widgets in App Widget hosts. As far as I can tell the basic Preferences screen is not a working app widget hosts.